# Make a field of an embeddable class transient from the embedding class in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, annotations

I have the following set of classes

```java
@Embeddable
public class SharedClass {
    ...
    private String legacyField;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class LongStandingEntity {
    ...
    private SharedClass sharedClass;
    ...
}
```

Where `legacyfield` stores some obsolete data in older objects but is not collected for new ones.  However I do need to able to continue to access the old data.

I'm creating a new entity that also makes use of `SharedClass`

```java
@Entity
public class NewEntity {
    ...
    private SharedClass sharedClass;
    ...
}
```

It doesn't need `legacyField` and I'd like to avoid having to add a column in the database for it whilst keeping the mapping working for `LongStandingEntity`.

Is this possible with JPA annotations?

Comment: Do you want to never store it or not store it in the new entities?

Comment: I just clarified that.  I need it for the old but not the new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall a particular annotation that can help you with that. Still I'd rather take a design approach with this situation. If you have field that belongs only to a certain class separate them in another embedabble class that's associated only with the older data.

Seems like a cleaner approach to me, just to keep entities clearly differenciated.

Comment: I've clarified my question:  I need to keep the mapping working for the old entities - just not the new one.

Comment: @scarba05 Cool, I've edited my answer. Not particulary what you ask for but an option instead, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I have found is to override the association with the parameters insertable=false and updatable=false.

```
@Entity
public class NewEntity {
    ...
    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name = "legacyField", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false))
    private SharedClass sharedClass;
    ...
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me,
instead I fixed the problem with 
@AttributeOverride(name = "legacyField", column =  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false))

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem as following

```
@Entity
public class NewEntity {
    ...
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "legacyField", column =  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false))
    })
    @Embedded
    private SharedClass sharedClass;
    ...
}
```

UPDATE
but when reading entity I get the
ERROR:  column new_entity_.legacyField does not exist at character 1504

so the problem is NOT fixed